# Remount a drive in a specific path with Chef

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, chef-infra

I am trying to remount a drive from a path that is in into another path. I am trying to do this with Chef Opscode. This drive is the ephemoral drive that comes with a m1.medium type if instance.

I am receiving this error-stacktrace when I run chef-client:

```
  Chef::Log.info("About to re-mount dev/xvdb in /testpath ")
  # Mount additional volumes for data, configure them via LVM
mount "/testpath" do
  device  "/dev/xvdb"
  # I am using Chef 10 and following the documentation on the mount resource
  action  [ :remount, :enable ]  
end
```

AND I see the following logs:

```
[2013-11-06T01:46:08+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2013-11-06T01:46:09+00:00] FATAL: Saving node information to /var/chef/cache/failed-run-data.json
[2013-11-06T01:46:09+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2013-11-06T01:46:09+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2013-11-06T01:46:09+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::UnsupportedAction: mount[/testpath] (my_cookbook::_my_recipe line 42) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::UnsupportedAction: #<Chef::Provider::Mount::Mount:0x000000046ad980> does not support :remount
```

Answer (score 1):

The relevent part of the log message

```
Chef::Exceptions::UnsupportedAction: #<Chef::Provider::Mount::Mount:0x000000046ad980> does not support :remount
```

Your device does not support the remount operation.

Comment: true. that was because It expects a path to be created first... see the directory resource I used below.

Answer (score 0):

So, the :remount command did not work for me but I tried :mount and that worked.

Plus I had to make sure that the directory called "/testpath" exists first...

So now I have smth like

```
Chef::Log.info("About to re-mount dev/xvdb in /testpath ")
  # Mount additional volumes for data, configure them via LVM
directory "/testpath" do
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode 00755
  action :create
end

mount "/testpath" do
  device  "/dev/xvdb"
  # I am using Chef 10 and following the documentation on the mount resource
map_point "/testpath"
  action  [ :remount, :enable ]  
end
```